# Зависает поток в цикле и не выходит

Tags: c#, многопоточность, циклы, while

Написал программу и поток зависал в цикле, впервый раз проверял код через дебаг и всё было окей, когда проверял в релизе зависло в цикле `while(count != 0)`  подавил в цикл `Thread.Sleep(200);` и всё заработало и в релизе. Вот примерная структура кода;

```
void start(int threadCount)
{
  int count = 0;
  foreach(var item in items)
  {
    while(count == threadCount) 
      Thread.Sleep(200);
    count++;
    new Thread(() =>
    {
       convert(param);
       count--;
    }).Start();
  }
  while(count != 0) //Зависает всё время здесь
  Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Зависало как говорил ранее когда в релизе попробовал  запустить, нашёл где виснет с помощью брекпойнтов и решил слипом проблему, после на длительной проверке программы с большим количеством данных (программа жрала оперативы не более 100мб) работает пару часов, потом может сам по себе в цикле этом встать и всё, вариант что `count` был не равным нулю отпадает, т.к. это проверял и значения после изменений для теста выводил, ума не приложу почему он там виснет и не перестаёт висеть, более двух часов ждал, он не отвисал, хотя все вызванные им потоки были завершены. Подскажите кто знает что я неправильно делаю

Comment: [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

Comment: Документацию по ссылке читали?

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно зависать. Переменная count не равна нулю. Запускается бесконечный цикл while(count != 0). Всё верно.
Если нужно чтобы чтобы основной поток ждал остальные используйте join().

Comment: Изучу join, но можете обьяснить почему должен зависать? ибо по факту поток работает, но иногда один из 100 раз зависает

Comment: Да и цикл не совсем бесконечный, ведь когда то всё таки count станет нулю и по сути цикл завершиться в этом и смысл

Comment: ну пробуй ставить брейкпоинт и проверять какое значение у каунта и увидишь. Ну или выводи значение каунта в консоль. Все работает как должно.

Comment: Сделал тестовое приложение, в дебаге работает всё ок, если в теле while нет ничего, то он всё равно ждёт пока count изменится на нужное значение, в а релизе по итогу если в ожидающем while нету в теле ничего, он тупо виснет, с помощью брекпойнтов отследил и вывел последнее значение count в textbox, итог count стало 0, но цикл while всё равно висит и не хочет выходить сколько не жди. Всё бы окей, решается вопрос обычным Thread.Sleep, но при длительной работе программы проскакивают аналогичные проблемы с ожидающим while, пока не разобрался как применять join для неименованных потоков...